# Can I create a "dead zone" on my magic trackpad?

Tags: macos, mac, magic-trackpad

I have my magic trackpad below my keyboard and it's great most of the time, but occasionally I hit the edges and end up clicking somewhere on the screen where I didn't want to click.

I tried putting a piece of masking tape, then a piece of plastic down the sides but it still picks up my hand through those.

Since I can't figure out a way to physically cover the edges so input is not read, is there some way with software / preferences to have the trackpad ignore movements at the very edges?

[image: trackpad 1.png]

Comment: Have you considered rolling up a small cloth napkin and taping that to the top? Doubles as a pseudo-wrist rest-ish.

Comment: I tried tape and plastic so far, I want to use it on the sides and bottom actually, but also want it to be really low profile. the tape and plastic don't phase the touch pad - maybe it is heat sensitive or pressure sensitive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your best best for a software-based solution is [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/).  If it doesn't do what you're looking for in this respect, it should come in handy anyway!

Comment: It's a great little app - was already using it. I don't see any options for creating a deadzone tho.